# Haskell error no instance from literal

Tags: haskell

Getting the following error:

```
• No instance for (Num [Int]) arising from the literal ‘5’
• In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘5’
In the expression: x == 5
In the expression: if x == 5 then True else False
```

When trying to load a haskell function:

```
listContainsFive :: [Int] -> Bool
listContainsFive [] = error "empty list"
listContainsFive x = if x == 5 then True else False
listContainsFive (x:xs) = listContainsFive xs
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, i'm very new to Haskell.

Comment: We usually say that that 5 does not belong to the empty list: returning an error is a bit extreme. You don't really need the singleton-list case. In the recursive case, you ignore the first element of the list, but that looks wrong.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, an easier way of formulating this (while still using explicit recursion) would be `lcf (5 : _) = True; lcf (_ : xs) = lcf xs; lcf [] = False`. A more idiomatic phrasing would be `lcf = any (== 5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `listContainsFive` has the type `[Int]`. So in `listContainsFive x = if x == 5 then True else False`, `x` has type `[Int]`. Since you're comparing `x` and `5` and both operands of `==` must have the same type, `5` must also have the type `[Int]`. The error message is GHC's way of telling you that it can't find a way to make `5` have a list type.

I'm not sure whether your intent was to match a single-element list and let `x` refer to the element of that list, or whether your intent was to have `x` refer to the head of any non-empty list. In the former case you should use the pattern `[x]` instead of `x`. In the latter case you should use the same pattern as on the following line (`(x:xs)`) - in fact you should merge those lines as the next pattern would be redundant otherwise.

Note that if your intent was to only match single-element lists with that pattern, your function will only check if 5 is the last element of a list while the name of the function suggests that it checks whether the list contains 5. So either your logic or your name would be wrong in that case.

Comment: Thanks, the [Int] was the code problem but my logic was also way off.

Answer (score 1):

Your type signature says that the argument is  `[Int]` (An Int list) but you are comparing it with `==` to `5` with is a single `Int`. You could pattern match for `x:[]`(or equivalently `[x]`) and then compare `x == 5`